# Use datepicker in railsadmin custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am trying use the same Datepicker Railadmin using for "Date" fields in my custom action.

I have date field in my custom action

```
<input type="text" class="hasDatepicker">
```

I can see rails_admin  using Jquery Ui Datepicker.

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-29 19:58:34 +0530
```

I also understood , they extending datapicker prototype.

```
$.extend(Datepicker.prototype, {
/* Class name added to elements to indicate already configured with a date picker. */
markerClassName: "hasDatepicker" ...
```

Any help for getting date picker to work in rails admin custom action (view) will be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `datepicker` class to the input field. i.e. `<input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker">`

Comment: @vinodadhikary : no Luck , <input type="text" name="from" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" value="">

Comment: @Senthill, sorry copy paste error.  Please try: `<input type="text" name="from" class="datepicker">`

Comment: @vinodadhikary , It won't work either Vinod. I already tested it. Is there any way to include the JS file in rails admin , so that we can import some other datepicker libraries.

Comment: @Senthill, Unsure as to why it's not working.  I just tested this, but in Rails 3.  Any errors you see in the console?  Also, how are you calling `datepicker` on this element (your javascript/coffeescript) code?

Comment: @Senthill, Please have a look at how I'm using it in the answer below.  If this doesn't work, please check for any errors in the browser console and make sure jquery.ui along with jquery.ui.datepicker is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by including external plugin. I added the JS library in Custom view itself.

```
<%=javascript_include_tag "/assets/rails_admin/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"%>
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/rails_admin/lib/datepicker.css"%>



function pick_date(){
      var nowTemp = new Date();
      var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var a=$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker({
                onRender: function(date) {
                  return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                },
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
              });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference this is how a working custom action view looks like with a working input that uses the rails admin datepicker

```
:javascript
  jQuery(function($) {
  $.filters.options.regional = {
    datePicker: {
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    dayNames: ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
    dayNamesShort: ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],
    firstDay: "1",
    monthNames: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
    monthNamesShort: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    }
  }

  });

:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker($.filters.options.regional);
  });

%form.pjax-form.form-inline{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :method => "get"}
  %div{:style => "display:none"}
    %input{:name => "utf8", :type => "hidden", :value => "✓"}/
  .well
    %span#filters_box
      %p.filter.form-search
        %span.label.label-info.form-label
          Created at
        %select.switch-additionnal-fieldsets.input-small{:name => "created_at"}
          %option{"data-additional-fieldset" => "default", :value => "default"} Date ...
          %option{"data-additional-fieldset" => "between", :value => "between"} Between ... and ...
          %option{:value => "today"} Today
          %option{:value => "yesterday"} Yesterday
          %option{:value => "this_week"} This week
          %option{:value => "last_week"} Last week
          %option{:disabled => "disabled"} ---------
          %option{:value => "_not_null"} Is present
          %option{:value => "_null"} Is blank
        %input.date.additional-fieldset.default.input-small{:name => "created_at", :style => "display:inline-block;", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
        %input.date.additional-fieldset.between.input-small{:name => "start_date", :placeholder => "-∞", :style => "display:none;", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
        %input.date.additional-fieldset.between.input-small{:name => "end_date", :placeholder => "∞", :style => "display:none;", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
        %button.btn.btn-primary{"data-disable-with" => "<i class='icon-white icon-refresh'></i> Refresh", :type => "submit"}
          %i.icon-white.icon-refresh
          Refresh
```

As you can see i had to add the regional stuff and call the datepicker myself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `datepicker` class to the input field. i.e.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

and use:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score -1):

To follow up on my comments above, here is how I'm using jquery.ui.datepicker which has worked without problems (note that the following code is an example):

**app/views/templates/model_action.html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :date_of_birth, id: 'user_date_of_birth', class: 'datepicker' %>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/datepicker.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('.datepicker').datepicker
```

**And the snippet from page source:**

```
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<input class="datepicker" id="user_date_of_birth" name="user[date_of_birth]" type="text" />
```

Comment: Its not Working Vinod, I am using rails 4 . I am sure js files are loading.

<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1"></script>